# Javascript won't render on webserver

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

First off I am a new member lurking for a very long time. A simple search with experimentation on my part generally answers my questions.

I am now experimenting with twitter bootstrap and Jquery. For some odd reason I can't get javascript to render on my websever. Its a clean server with nginx installed.

To test, Its a simple script to load tab 1. Just won't work.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">

        <li class="active span4 text-center"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Protecting your data </a></li>

        <li class="span4 text-center"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Built-in Compliance </a></li>

        <li class="span4 text-center"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Easy IT Administration </a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
            <p>Protecting your data</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
            <p>Built-in Compliance</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
            <p>This is tab 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

<!-- script to display first tab by default -->


<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#tabs a:first').tab('show');
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code here, please?

Comment: Please do not link to external resources that can change. This will make your question useless to other people in the future.

Comment: Sorry - I removed the external site and added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
NOtworking =>>>> $('#tabs a').first().tab('show');



EDIT
```

It seems your page has some funk.  If you select another tab first it will work so...

```
$('#tabs a').tab('show').first().tab('show')
```

/* FINAL ISSUE FOUND */

After tinking with the issue.  It seems the `active` class is the problem.  Remove that from your first li and you're good.

Comment: Damn - this worked. How do folks learn all this stuff.

Comment: Everything's a puzzle.  Fun to figure out.

Comment: @Bluetoft Yep, if you want to use the active class in this way, you have to put it on the content and the li.  I didn't notice they they already had an active on one of them.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first tab is selected by default, so trying to tell it to select that tab does nothing.  But the content is not shown because it doesn't get shown by default. You need to put the active class on the li AND the tab.  So you can either start out with a default tab with active on both tab and content:

`<li class="active span4 text-center active">`

`<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">`

http://jsfiddle.net/s4d8x/1/

Or you can flip to a different tab and then back:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6hJ9/